# What exactly is a Humble Monthly Sneak Peek?

Tags: humble-bundle

The Humble Monthly February bundle contains an "exclusive sneak peek" of Hollow Knight. Is this a demo? Is it the full game in an unfinished state? If it is currently unfinished, will it be updated when the game is finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not the full games, and usually consist of a demo to play.

Here is a quote about a game listed as a "sneak peek" back in the [February 2016 bundle](https://www.humblebundle.com/monthly/p/february_2016_monthly):

> "This sneak peek demo is a bite-sized taste of our new game Planetoid
>   Pioneers, which we will ship on Steam Early Access on April 15th this
>   year."
>   - Data Realms

## Edit:

It is possible that they are demos of a finished game, which usually means the developer didn't want to give away the whole game to HumbleBundle, or it means that it is in fact an unfinished game and it's a genuine sneak peek at a product they intend to release eventually; however, if they do not specifically state that you will eventually be given the game, you will not be given the full game upon release.